# Memory overflow error Joomla

Tags: memory, joomla, overflow

I'm not very experienced with Joomla. I've installed Joomla 3.3 and Uber 1.0 as a template. I created two languages, English and Italian, and the menu which has to redirect the user.
But when I try to surf the site I get this error:

```
Warning: touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted in /usr/local/psa/home/vhosts/oikosarredamenti.it/httpdocs/plugins/system/t3/includes/core/less.php on line 422 Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in /usr/local/psa/home/vhosts/oikosarredamenti.it/httpdocs/plugins/system/t3/includes/lessphp/less/less.php on line 5401
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the Joomla Baackend, go to:

**System** (top menu) >> **System Information** >> **Directory Permissions**

and check that the cache folder is writable. If not, then change the permissions to **775** using an FTP Client such as FileZilla or a Joomla extension such as Admin Tools.

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I modified site permissions to 777, but nothing changed. I changed the theme and that worked...

Comment: Hmm, try asking your question over at [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) ;)